# change the css of anchor tag inside clicked div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple div with classes

> .product_wishlist

I want to change the color of the particular anchor tag on which the user click inside this div, but now all the anchor tag colors which are inside .pw div are changed. Is it possible to add selected css to the clicked element. Please help to sort out my issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.pw',function(e){
    $('.pw > a').css('background-color', 'green');
  });
});
```

```css
.product_wishlist > a {
    background-color: #e91e63;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    z-index: 9;
}

.wishlish-selected > a {
    background-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product_wishlist pw">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="ti-heart"></i>Wishlist</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to refer the current element and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the *anchor* element from that:

Change

```
$('.pw > a').css('background-color', 'green');
```

To

```
$(this).find('a').css('background-color', 'green');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.pw',function(e){
    $(this).find('a').addClass('wishlish-selected')
  });
});
```

```css
.wishlish-selected{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product_wishlist pw">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="ti-heart"></i>Wishlist 1</a>
</div>
<div class="product_wishlist pw">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="ti-heart"></i>Wishlist 2</a>
</div>
<div class="product_wishlist pw">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="ti-heart"></i>Wishlist 3</a>
</div>
```

As you already specifying the *anchor* element after the class in the CSS selector, you do not need to find *anchor* element again in jQuery, simply add the class to the current element. Also, there is an issue with `position: absolute`, to show the output I ignored that property here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.pw',function(e){
    $(this).addClass('wishlish-selected')
  });
});
```

```css
.product_wishlist > a {
    background-color: #e91e63;
    height: 30px;
    right: -32px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    z-index: 9;
}

.wishlish-selected > a {
    background-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    right: -32px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product_wishlist pw">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="ti-heart"></i>Wishlist 1</a>
</div>
<div class="product_wishlist pw">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="ti-heart"></i>Wishlist 2</a>
</div>
<div class="product_wishlist pw">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="ti-heart"></i>Wishlist 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can i do something like this because it will be easier for me to count $(this).find('a').addClass('wishlish-selected');. but nright now it is not working.

Comment: Thanks Mamun, but there is a css that is already defined .product_wishlist > a {
    background-color: #e91e63;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    z-index: 9;
}            which is overriding my wishlish-selected.